# Elasticsearch daily rolling index contains duplicate _id

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

this maybe a silly question but I am using the daily rolling index to save my events with logstash, the config is simple as:

```
input: {..source..}
filter: {..filter..}
output: {
 elasticsearch: {
   document_id: %{my_own_guarantee_unique_id}
   index: myindex-%{+YYYY.MM.DD}
 }
}
```

what I found was if there are events with same  `my_own_guarantee_unique_id` appears on different days, it will be created multiple times in these daily rolling indexes, ie. you can find event that has _id = 123 appearing in myindex-2015.06.21 and myindex-2015.06.22

is this sort of duplicate out of box? what should I do to avoid it? any suggestion or readings will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using multiple indexes, one for every day, you can get the same _id. What makes a document unique is the uid, which is a combination of index,type and id. There is no way in elastic to change this to my knowledge.

Comment: that makes sense Jettro. Since I'm using logstash, is there a way to use `_uid` instead of `_id` on saving documents?

Comment: If what you want to do is update the document if a document with the same id comes a long than you could insert them in one big index by changing the template of the index in your log stash configuration. The problem is that there is no relationship between indexes. No way to control uniqueness over different indexes.

Comment: agreed Jettro, I ended up with making a custom logstash filter that sends a query to related indices by wild card (logstash-*) for records with that `_id` and if there are existing ones and not belongs to current day's index, it will remove them and insert the current event to current index instead - a bit clumsy but works

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue: several duplicated documents with the same id but in different indexes (I have 1 index / date).

What worked for me was to generate a field with the index name and reuse it in the output part of the logstash configuration.

```
index => "%{index_name}"
document_id => "%{clickID}"
```